# How do I run Guava's benchmark suite?

Tags: maven, guava, benchmarking, caliper

Guava has a `guava-tests` subdirectory that contains a directory subtree called `benchmark`. It appears that executing `mvn test` (or `mvn install`) runs the full suite of unit tests in the `test` subtree, but nothing is run in the benchmarks suite.

My question is: **how do you actually run the benchmark suite?** In other words, if I download the guava source from git (say, in a Linux environment), what are the steps I need to take to build guava and run its benchmark suite locally?

There is surprisingly little information about this online. I stumbled across this old [Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/5SZKjiu4UWc), as well as a [git issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1642) about adding documentation for this, but I haven't found much else.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [comment](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1642#issuecomment-61353796) by cgdecker it seems you cannot (easily) run the benchmarks since they don't even compile externally. For now they're effectively released simply for reference. Clearly the Guava team *intends* to let external users run the benchmarks, but it hasn't been done yet. Commenting on the bug, especially if you include use-case information (i.e. say more than just "+1"), would presumably help them prioritize getting this done.