# What is the proper number of stripes for Guava Striped?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, guava

I want to provide locking access to a resource using Guava Striped Lock. E.g.

```
Striped<Lock> keyLocks = Striped.lazyWeakLock(10)
Lock lock = keyLocks.get("resourceId")
// use lock...
```

I cannot find any guide how to choose the correct number of stripes for:

```
Striped.lazyWeakLock(int stripes)
```

Should `stripes` be bound to the number of processor cores or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no a general rule of thumb, it depends on a trade-off between concurrency level and memory consumption. The `Striped` JavaDoc partially explains it:

> A striped `Lock/Semaphore/ReadWriteLock`. This offers the underlying
>   lock striping similar to that of `ConcurrentHashMap` in a reusable form,
>   and extends it for semaphores and read-write locks. **Conceptually, lock
>   striping is the technique of dividing a lock into many stripes,
>   increasing the granularity of a single lock and allowing independent
>   operations to lock different stripes and proceed concurrently, instead
>   of creating contention for a single lock.**
>
> The guarantee provided by
>   this class is that equal keys lead to the same lock (or semaphore),
>   i.e. if `key1.equals(key2)` then `striped.get(key1) == striped.get(key2)` (assuming `Object.hashCode()` is correctly implemented
>   for the keys). Note that if `key1` is not equal to `key2`, it is not
>   guaranteed that `striped.get(key1) != striped.get(key2)`; the elements
>   might nevertheless be mapped to the same lock. **The lower the number of
>   stripes, the higher the probability of this happening.**
>
> ...
>
> Prior to this class, one might be tempted to use `Map<K, Lock>`, where `K` represents the task. **This maximizes concurrency by having each unique key mapped to a unique lock, but also maximizes memory footprint. On the other extreme, one could use a single lock for all tasks, which minimizes memory footprint but also minimizes concurrency. Instead of choosing either of these extremes, `Striped` allows the user to trade between required concurrency and memory footprint.** For example, if a set of tasks are CPU-bound, one could easily create a very compact `Striped<Lock> of availableProcessors() * 4` stripes, instead of possibly thousands of locks which could be created in a `Map<K, Lock>` structure.

In other words, `Striped` provides a flexibility to select a number of locks, which are distributed between the keys, based on their hash code. This allows to dynamically apply a trade-off between concurrency and memory footprint, while retaining the key invariant that if `key1.equals(key2)`, then `striped.get(key1) == striped.get(key2)`.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The general idea about stripes is clear from the JavaDoc. The question is about practical usage.

Comment: Well, your question cannot be answered directly, it highly depends on the context/usage. If you don't care about memory consumption per lock and want to achieve highest concurrency, use `65535` as a seed value. If you do care, and want to achieve some concurrency use `2, 4, 8, 16, 32` etc.

Comment: You can refer to this [official Benchmark](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava-tests/benchmark/com/google/common/util/concurrent/StripedBenchmark.java) for precise numbers. Although it's [quite a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996056/how-do-i-run-guavas-benchmark-suite) to run them or to [find benchmark results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189442/is-there-published-guava-benchmark-results-available).